# dask-yarn on cluster: Unable to connect to application

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop-yarn, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to use dask-yarn to distribute Python jobs on a cluster.

I'm using the following code to create the cluster:

```py
from dask_yarn import YarnCluster

cluster = YarnCluster(environment='.conda/envs/myconda', worker_vcores=2, worker_memory='4GB', n_workers=4)
client = Client(cluster)
cluster.shutdown()
```

I would have assumed that you would need more info to make sure that it is connected to the yarn.

The error message is as shown below:

````py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-9de74c663703> in <module>()
----> 1 cluster = YarnCluster('myconda.tar.gz')

~/.conda/envs/myconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_yarn/core.py in __init__(self, environment, n_workers, worker_vcores, worker_memory, worker_restarts, worker_env, scheduler_vcores, scheduler_memory, deploy_mode, name, queue, tags, user, skein_client)
    293                                    user=user)
    294 
--> 295         self._start_cluster(spec, skein_client)
    296 
    297     @cached_property

~/.conda/envs/myconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_yarn/core.py in _start_cluster(self, spec, skein_client)
    373             app = skein_client.submit_and_connect(spec)
    374             try:
--> 375                 scheduler_address = app.kv.wait('dask.scheduler').decode()
    376                 dashboard_address = app.kv.get('dask.dashboard')
    377                 if dashboard_address is not None:

~/.conda/envs/myconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skein/kv.py in wait(self, key, return_owner)
    653                 return res
    654 
--> 655             event = event_queue.get()
    656 
    657         return event.result if return_owner else event.result.value

~/.conda/envs/myconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skein/kv.py in get(self, block, timeout)
    279         if isinstance(out, Exception):
    280             self._exception = out
--> 281             raise out
    282         return out
    283 

ConnectionError: Unable to connect to application
```python
````

Comment: Just to add, this is in a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your application failed to start (and thus can't connect). I recommend looking at the logs:

```
$ yarn logs -applicationId <YOUR APPLICATION ID>
```

From looking at your code above, one odd thing is the conda environment specified. It looks like you're passing the path of a directory instead of an archived environment - you may want to read the documentation here: http://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/environments.html.